# Enable/Disable select/dropdown and Radio button on dropdown selected?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to Enable/Disable the Radio button and select/Dropdown on dropdown selected.

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/thorstorm1102/1sm2uxtb/38/)

Ex: If `persons` is selected only `name="persons"`(Anthony and Paul) and `person dropdown` must be available to select and Rest must be disabled

```
        <select class="browser-default" id="type" name="type">
        <option value="persons">persons</option>
        <option value="animals">animals</option>
        <option value="fruits">fruits</option>
        </select>

        <br/>

        <label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="apple" id="apple" title="">Apple</label>
        <br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="banana" id="banana" title="">Banana</label>
        <br/>

        <label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="dog" id="dog" title="">Dog</label>
        <br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="cat" id="cat" title="">Cat</label>
        <br/>


        <label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="anthony" id="anthony" title="">Anthony</label>
        <br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="paul" id="paul" title="">Paul</label>
        <br/>

        <select class="browser-default" id="persons1" name="persons">
        <option value="1">Person Dropdown</option>
        </select>
        <br/> 

        <select class="browser-default" id="animals1" name="animals">
        <option value="1">Animals Dropdown</option>
        </select>
        <br/> 

        <select class="browser-default" id="fruits1" name="fruits">
        <option value="1">Fruits Dropdown</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
```

What I have tried:

Only Radio buttons without select/dropdown,

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        $("input").prop("checked", false);
        $("input").prop('disabled', false);
        $("input[type='radio']").prop("disabled", true);
        $("input[name='" + $(this).val() + "']").prop("disabled", false);
    }).trigger("change");
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 function disabled_all(){
  $('input[name="fruits"],input[name="animals"],input[name="fruits"], select[name="persons"],select[name="animals"],select[name="fruits"]').prop('disabled', true);
  }
 
 disabled_all();
 
 $('.browser-default').on('change', function () {
    var type = $(this).val();
    disabled_all();
    $('input[name="' + type + '"], select[name="' + type + '"]').prop('disabled', false);
}).trigger('chnage');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="browser-default" id="type" name="type">
        <option value="persons">persons</option>
        <option value="animals">animals</option>
        <option value="fruits">fruits</option>
        </select>

        <br/>

        <label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="apple" id="apple" title="">Apple</label>
        <br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="banana" id="banana" title="">Banana</label>
        <br/>

        <label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="dog" id="dog" title="">Dog</label>
        <br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="cat" id="cat" title="">Cat</label>
        <br/>


        <label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="anthony" id="anthony" title="">Anthony</label>
        <br/>
        <label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="paul" id="paul" title="">Paul</label>
        <br/>

        <select class="browser-default" id="persons1" name="persons">
        <option value="1">Person Dropdown</option>
        </select>
        <br/> 

        <select class="browser-default" id="animals1" name="animals">
        <option value="1">Animals Dropdown</option>
        </select>
        <br/> 

        <select class="browser-default" id="fruits1" name="fruits">
        <option value="1">Fruits Dropdown</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all radio button which have same name and enabled that radio button.Also ,to enable select-box use  `$("select[name='" + $(this).val() + "']").prop("disabled", false);`  .

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#type").change(function() {
  //disable other select
   $('select:not(#type)').prop("disabled", true);
    $("input").prop("checked", false);
    $("input").prop('disabled', false);
    $("input[type='radio']").prop("disabled", true);
    //looping through all inputs
  $("input[name='" + $(this).val() + "']").each(function(){
   $(this).prop("disabled", false); //remove disable
  })
  //remove disabled from slect
 $("select[name='" + $(this).val() + "']").prop("disabled", false);
 

  }).trigger("change");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="browser-default" id="type" name="type">
  <option value="persons">persons</option>
  <option value="animals">animals</option>
  <option value="fruits">fruits</option>
</select>

<br/>

<label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="apple" id="apple" title="">Apple</label>
<br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="fruits" value="banana" id="banana" title="">Banana</label>
<br/>

<label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="dog" id="dog" title="">Dog</label>
<br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="animals" value="cat" id="cat" title="">Cat</label>
<br/>


<label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="anthony" id="anthony" title="">Anthony</label>
<br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="persons" value="paul" id="paul" title="">Paul</label>
<br/>

<select class="browser-default" id="persons1" name="persons">
  <option value="1">Person Dropdown</option>
</select>
<br/>

<select class="browser-default" id="animals1" name="animals">
  <option value="1">Animals Dropdown</option>
</select>
<br/>

<select class="browser-default" id="fruits1" name="fruits">
  <option value="1">Fruits Dropdown</option>
</select>
<br/>
```